# Merge two persistent caches in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

My application uses Apache Ignite persistent storage. For some weeks I ran the application storing the persistent data in let's say "c:\db1". Later I ran the same application with persistent data in c:\db2. The data was only stored on this one server node.
Is there a way to merge the data from db1 folder to db2 folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, at least not easily.

The best way would be two start two nodes in *separate* clusters, one using `c:\db1` and one using `c:\db2` and stream data from one to the other:

1. Start the two clusters
2. Start a helper application that will load the data
3. In the application, start two client nodes with different configurations - one connected to the first cluster, one connected to the second
4. Transfer the data roughly like this (code is not tested!)

   ```
   IgniteCache cache1 = client1.cache("mycache");
   IgniteCache cache2 = client2.cache("mycache");
   for (Cache.Entry e : cache1.query(new ScanQuery())) {
       client2.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted. However, this would require me to run both servers at the same time in isolated clusters. That makes sense to avoid shutting down the cluster. In the end it's been easier for me to export all cache items from db1 into serialized files on disk, then import afterwards into db2. Thanks anyway!